# in go, why []int instead of int[]?

Tags: syntax, go

this syntax was started quite some time ago, and I do not understand its appeal

to me, even with initialization,

```
var arr int[2]{ 1, 2 }  // wrong!
```

is more readable than

```
var arr [2]int{ 1, 2 }  // to me this seems klutzy
```

---

before more people get on my case, please see notes, and link in answer was exactly the info I was seeking.

Comment: I don't understand the appeal of pants, but I wear them anyway. :)

Comment: @chris - I love computer languages, and like to understand why decisions were made.  see link in answer - for me, very cool

Comment: from link, two main points: "One value of this left-to-right style is how well it works as the types become more complex", and "The distinction between type and expression syntax makes it easy to write and invoke closures in Go"

Comment: @cc young: kidding, of course. Scala actually made the same decision for the reasons you just cited.

Comment: Why was this guy downvoted? Looks like a legitimate question in language design.

Comment: ffs, sometimes I think that subjective questions should be allowed. Maybe they shouldn't give reputation or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second way is more readable to me. It's an opinion thing. Since you didn't create the language, your opinion wasn't the one adopted.

There may have also been other factors, such as the second way being easier to parse.

Here's [a blog post](http://blog.golang.org/2010/07/gos-declaration-syntax.html) on the Go syntax choices. It sounds like it was mostly about readability.

Also, this difference from C might play a part (found [here](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#arrays)):

> The size of an array is part of its
>   type. The types [10]int and [20]int
>   are distinct.